# How can I keep this loop going until balance is zero?

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript and have figured how to make the first line log to the console, however, how can I continue the loop and display the results as the balance gets lower until the balance is zero? I appreciate any help with this.  Thanks in advance.

```
function displayPayment() {
  var year = 0;
  var balance = 1500;
  var interest = 0.015;
  var minimum = 0.02;
  var payNum = 0;

  if (balance > 0) {
    var newPayNum = payNum + 1;
    var newYear = year + 1;
    var interestPaid = balance * interest;
    var newBalance = interestPaid + balance;
    var minPay = newBalance * minimum;
    var balanceOwe = newBalance - minPay;

    return ("   " + newYear + "   " + balanceOwe + "      " + newPayNum + "            
" + interestPaid);
  }
}
console.log(" Year " + " Balance " + " PaymentNum " + "  InterestPaid \n");
console.log(displayPayment());
```

Comment: Where is the loop?

Comment: "_how can I continue the loop and display the results as the balance gets lower until the balance is zero?_" 1) Make a loop 2) Decrease `balance` in the loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can use either the `do while` loop or just a `while` loop. However your balance does not change during the process, so the loop will never exit.